# How can I start writing a program in python where it reads an excel file with few records and generate more record for testing purpose

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-generation, msdatasetgenerator

I have got a file with 5 rows and multiple columns and that when read by the program it should generate 100 records for example which can then be loaded into database.
Format can be excel or csv

Comment: Try to have a look on SMOTE algorithm, which creates new data from your existing ones. (5 might be a bit low to be honest)

Answer (score 0):

Let's save you have a file `file.csv`. Read that into a dataframe and sample from it as many times as you need. Write the result to a new dataframe or csv.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
new_df = df.sample(n=100, replace=True) # n could be as big as you want

# new df can now be exported
new_df.to_csv('new_df.csv')
```

Comment: But i dont want to duplicate same data. Could use some package and generate new data similar to the data in that column